# Json parsing in IBM Worklight

Tags: json, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to achieve something like which is mentioned in this [link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/using_ibm_worklight_http_adapters_with_rest_json_services7?lang=en)

but i don't know whereto write the parsing code. I tried to write it in new method and added the method in "my adapter.xml" but nothing happens. I even don't know how to log in IBM WorkLight. I used WL.logger(some) but its throwing error that "Logger can not be called on an object".

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases you don't need to manually parse responses because WL adapter framework will do this for you. Anything you retrieve via WL.Server.invokeHttp API will be parsed to JSON automatically unless you specify returnedContentType:"plain". In case you DO need to manually parse JSON you can use JSON.parse() and JSON.stringify() APIs.

Server side logging is achieved via WL.Logger.debug/error/info etc. You can get more info about it [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/logging_and_debugging_on_worklight_server?lang=en)

Comment: thanks for your time Anton. I want to parse the json object to find some particular field for e.g.: latitude and longitude under location, how will i do that? I think i need to use manual parsing to achieve this.  and also can you provide some link as reference for JSON.parse() i.e how to use it in IBM WL.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to parse JSON data, there are libraries in Javascript to do that. Try `JSON.parse()`.  You should learning how to write adapters and invoking them from clients. The [Getting Started modules](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/start/c_gettingstarted.html) are a good place to start, specifically Module 4 in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your time Srik. I already know how to write adapters and invoke them from client. My concern is how to parse json in IBM Worklight and how to log in adapter. anyways, thanks again.